# ckeditor official demo can paste image from clipboard why I can't?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

http://ckeditor.com/demo

The ckeditor demo (standard) in above links can direct paste image from clipboard. but when I click to download the standard version I can't paste image in the sample html. why ?

what should I do so that my build In include function of paste image from clipboard available by default ?

regards
Yeong

Comment: Check out the clipboard plugins and make sure you have the right one included in your setup.

Comment: Are you tested the `HTML` in a local server?

Comment: @Bindrid clipboard plugins are in the standard packages so how should I set up the image paste from clipboard function ? because I can't find the documentation for this setup.

Comment: @elchininet I tested in HTML sample without WAMP, and wrote a php file and run in WAMP. i guess there is something I need to setup the path to store the image and activate this function in editor but I don't have hint to do it.

Comment: The version I have came with a sample page.  I was able to copy and pasted an image with that version (also standard).  My suggestion is to test to see if it works on the sample that came with your download.

Comment: In the standard package I do not see CKFinder (The demo that you mentioned uses CKFinder). CKFinder is used to upload files (in this case, the image on clipboard).

Comment: @Bindrid   my version sample files is only available to paste if the img have a url link, but if is something like "print screen" then is unable to paste, but the demo on official website can paste img of print screen from clipboard without url.

Comment: Ok, that was interesting. With IE 11, it worked as advertised. With Firefox, I get a popup that I have to paste into, then it works. Chrome does not work on my local box but it does at their website.  Edge does not work on my local box either.  Did you try cntl-v   instead of right clicking then pasting?

Comment: It does work here: http://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/simpleuploads.demo4/  but note that the text right above the plugin show at this link says something about having a licensed version.

Comment: @Bindrid  thanks for reply after you mention in IE11 i try to pay attention about the sample file while open in IE11, then I click allow ActiveX in the pop up, after that I can paste img with ctrl V, but same as you said in chrome and firefox this function is not working, maybe something do with ActiveX, but it was interesting that the official demo are work on chrome and firefox.

Comment: Did you checkout the part about having a licensed version in that link?

Comment: Mine is the freebie unlicensed version.

Comment: @Bindrid Yes I checkout the link and view around the licensed version, thanks a lot ! but I am thinking to switch to UEditor since they also provide same function in original build in.